# Extract a correct 16x16 icon assigned to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, icons, shell-icons

I tied SHGetFileInfo and ExtractIconEx, both return a normal 32x32 icon and 16x16 with only 16 colors, and it looks awful. How do I extract a full color icon?

My code

```
SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
IntPtr hImgSmall = SHGetFileInfo(fileName, 0, ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
Icon icon = (Icon)System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon).Clone();
DestroyIcon(shinfo.hIcon);
```

Comment: Are you sure that file you trying to extract small icon has full color 16x16 icon?

Comment: At least the windows explorer shows it.
http://img196.imageshack.us/i/iconsdys.png/

Comment: That is strange, it must work, at least it work in my case. You absolutely need Icon, or Image is also acceptable?

Comment: I convert finally from Icon to Image as icon.ToBitmap(). The result you could see above.

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried the following?

```
Icon LargeIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileName);
Icon SmallIcon = new Icon(LargeIcon, 16, 16);
```

Comment: An extracted icon has the only bitmap so it just distorts the image.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this example [link text](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial219_Extracting-Icons-from-Files.html) and works.....got 16*16 with alpha channel.
Try it.

Comment: Confirm this works.  Seems you must call ToBitmap() else you will only get 16 colors!  thanks

Comment: Wow, this is the only one that I can get to work. out of like the 20 I have found on google. This one rules!

Comment: This is the reason why u should post the code not a link. The link is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a working how-to here: http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;319350&x=14&y=9